# how to create a count variable that counts based on the value of a binary variable in R using dplyr while also counting zero observations

Tags: r

This is a follow up question of my last question: code to create df: I have the repeat data that looks like the table below.

```
df <- structure(list(patid = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
                         "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5"), observation_date = c("07/07/2016", 
                                                                        "07/08/2016", "07/11/2016", "07/07/2019", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
                                                                        "07/05/2015", "07/06/2015", "16/06/2015", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
                                                                        "18/12/2016", "15/01/2017", "18/12/2016", "15/01/2017"),
                      registration = c("0","0","1","1","0","1","0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                          -13L))
```

| patid | observation_date | registration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07/07/2016 | 0 |
| 1 | 07/08/2016 | 0 |
| 1 | 07/11/2016 | 1 |
| 1 | 07/07/2019 | 1 |
| 2 | 07/05/2015 | 0 |
| 2 | 02/12/2016 | 1 |
| 3 | 07/05/2015 | 0 |
| 3 | 07/06/2015 | 0 |
| 3 | 16/06/2015 | 0 |
| 4 | 07/05/2015 | 0 |
| 4 | 02/12/2016 | 1 |
| 4 | 18/12/2016 | 1 |
| 4 | 15/01/2017 | 1 |
| 5 | 18/12/2016 | 1 |
| 5 | 15/01/2017 | 1 |

I would like to summarize data in this way: I want two rows only for each patid, one row will have a count of the observation_date when value of registration=0 and one row will have a count of the observation_date when value of registration=1. I used the code below which helped me create the table but it completely ignores those patients that don't have an observation at all when registration is 1 or 0. In that case, I still want it to say 0 because with the current code it completely ignores patients that don't have an observation.

```
df %>% 
  count(patid, registration = factor(registration), .drop = FALSE)
```

The final table should look like this:

| patid | registration | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `complete`:

```
df <- data.frame(list(patid = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
                               "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5"), observation_date = c("07/07/2016", 
                                                                                        "07/08/2016", "07/11/2016", "07/07/2019", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
                                                                                        "07/05/2015", "07/06/2015", "16/06/2015", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
                                                                                        "18/12/2016", "15/01/2017", "18/12/2016", "15/01/2017"),
                     registration = c("0","0","1","1","0","1","0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","1")))

df %>% group_by(patid) %>%
 count(registration, name = 'count') %>%
 complete(registration, fill = list(count = 0))
```

### Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   patid [5]
   patid registration   count
   <fct> <fct>        <int>
 1 1     0                2
 2 1     1                2
 3 2     0                1
 4 2     1                1
 5 3     0                3
 6 3     1                0
 7 4     0                1
 8 4     1                3
 9 5     0                0
10 5     1                2
```